# how do I find where apt-get installs files belonging to a package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, aptitude

I installed a package with apt-get, and now I need to locate where these files have been placed.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-cache show <package>
```

and,

```
sudo find / -name <package>
```

but it did not reveal anything useful.

Whats a good command or method to find the files belonging to a specific package I installed? I'm using Ubuntu 10.x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dpkg -L package_name` lists all files belonging to a package `package_name`

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, Debian also provides apt-file which can do the same as `dpkg -L` for remote files.